# Многоуровневое меню bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

вот код

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn-small pull-right dropdown-toggle">Добавить<span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a href="#"><small>Договор<span class="caret"></span></small></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#"><small>Дополнительное соглашение о вселении членов семьи</small></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><small>Дополнительное соглашение о выбытии членов семьи</small></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><small>Доп. соглашение<span class="caret"></span></small></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><small>Заявления<span class="caret"></span></small></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><small>Акты<span class="caret"></span></small></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Первый выпадающий список работает, второй -нет. Читала, что в третьем бутстрапе многоуровневость не предусмотрена. Как получить результат?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-3-dropdown-sub-menu-missing

Answer (score 2):

Возможно Вас заинтересует это [пример](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3) или [этот](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-navbar-menu)

Первый пример HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Multi level dropdown menu in Bootstrap 3</h2>
        <hr>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
                Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
              <li><a href="#">Some action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Some other action</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Hover me for more options</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a href="#">Even More..</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

Второй пример HTML

```
<style>
            body {
                padding-top: 50px;
            }
            .navbar-template {
                padding: 40px 15px;
            }

        </style>
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NavBar</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://github.com/fontenele/bootstrap-navbar-dropdowns" target="_blank">GitHub</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu 1 <b class="caret"></b></a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action [Menu 1.1]</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action [Menu 1.1]</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here [Menu 1.1]</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link [Menu 1.1]</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link [Menu 1.1]</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown [Menu 1.1] <b class="caret"></b></a>

                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Action [Menu 1.2]</a></li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown [Menu 1.2] <b class="caret"></b></a>

                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown [Menu 1.3] <b class="caret"></b></a>

                                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                        <li><a href="#">Action [Menu 1.4]</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Another action [Menu 1.4]</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Something else here [Menu 1.4]</a></li>
                                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Separated link [Menu 1.4]</a></li>
                                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link [Menu 1.4]</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu 2 <b class="caret"></b></a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action [Menu 2.1]</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action [Menu 2.1]</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here [Menu 2.1]</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link [Menu 2.1]</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link [Menu 2.1]</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown [Menu 2.1] <b class="caret"></b></a>

                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Action [Menu 2.2]</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Another action [Menu 2.2]</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Something else here [Menu 2.2]</a></li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Separated link [Menu 2.2]</a></li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown [Menu 2.2] <b class="caret"></b></a>

                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown [Menu 2.3] <b class="caret"></b></a>

                                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                        <li><a href="#">Action [Menu 2.4]</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Another action [Menu 2.4]</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Something else here [Menu 2.4]</a></li>
                                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Separated link [Menu 2.4]</a></li>
                                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link [Menu 2.4]</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-template text-center">
                <h1>Bootstrap NavBar (Updated: 15 Nov 2016)</h1>
                <p class="lead text-info">NavBar with too many childs.</p>
            </div>

        </div><!-- /.container -->
```

CSS

```
@media (min-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .caret {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
}
```

И немножко javascript (jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navbar a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
        var $el = $(this);
        var $parent = $(this).offsetParent(".dropdown-menu");
        $(this).parent("li").toggleClass('open');

        if(!$parent.parent().hasClass('nav')) {
            $el.next().css({"top": $el[0].offsetTop, "left": $parent.outerWidth() - 4});
        }

        $('.nav li.open').not($(this).parents("li")).removeClass("open");

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/135915)

Comment: Вы имеете в виду копипаст?

Comment: Это автоматический текст, который проставляется роботом, когда участники делают проверки постов низкого качества (например, слишком короткие сообщения). В принципе, если у вас не хватает времени на полноценный ответ, но хочется помочь топикстартеру -- то просто напишите это в комментариях, это хорошая практика. Если хочется расписать ответ -- то лучше сделать это своими словами, вычленив главное, а не по-диагонали копируя.

Comment: Спасибо, буду иметь в виду